# How to use an async timer

Tags: python, android, asynchronous

I have a Python Server running on Win10, communicating with an Android App (written in JavaScript) as a Client, using Sockets.

While the App is in the foreground everything works OK. Once the App is sent to the background (depending on available memory in the mobile), communication stops, and the Server hangs waiting for a reply from the Client.

I could find no way to keep the Android App if the foreground, and I do not have the source code.

The only solution I could think of is to have an Async timer, which after (say 60 seconds) signals the Server to terminate the App, and re-open the Server awaiting for the App to re-connect.

Here is my PSEUDO code:

```
OpenSocket()                     # waits for Client to connect

while True:
    send(message)                # to Client
    start async.timer            # sleep for 60 seconds 
    timer != finished:
        reset timer
        rec = receive.message()  # do processing 
    else:
        send(TerminatingMessage)
        OpenSocket()
```

I would appreciate any help to code the above !

Answer (score 0):

When an app is in the background on Android it's rapidly killed off.  Within 2 minutes.  To prevent that you could use a foreground service.  That will increase the length of time it stays alive, but will not help permanently.  It also will not help if the phone screen is turned off.  When the screen is off you enter a power saving mode called Doze, where apps only get a brief window for IO every 15 minutes.

Basically-  this type of architecture is inappropriate for an Android app.  Your best bet is to rearchitect.  High priority push messages can restart your app if its killed while backgrounded and can override Doze, so long as you don't send too many.  Beyond that, we'd need to know how often your app sends and receives data and how important it is that it's timely to help.

Comment: When you talk about 2 minutes before termination since which SDK do you observe this time frame? Before Android 5 I was able to keep a project up to 10 minutes. This question is just for keep platform knowledge up to date. Regarding the topic starter issue I would also add app might be killed during the lack of memory, but you are able to track this by listening a special broadcast intent. Also Android ```radio-state-machine``` stays active up to 18 seconds after each data transfer and goes to low consumed mode. If you wouldn't take in mind your app design it will quickly *drain* your battery.

Comment: @Gleichmut Android 5 is ancient, we're on 13 now.  Yes, the 2 minute strict timer is more recent than that, but even back on 5 any background service or activity could be killed at any time for any reason.  Android isn't a stable place for background processes, by design.  And no, you can't track when your app is killed while backgrounded-  it's jut killed.

Comment: yes, that's correct. I was interesting about experience based observations. Even if it just had been done in the lab.